# Is it true that there are infinite palindromic primes that when squared give palindromic number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elementary-proofs, palindromes

Can you prove that there are infinite palindromic primes that when squared give a palindromic number?

Comment: 2,3,11,101 --- it is seems unknown if there are more.

Comment: Crlo Beenakker yeah I know but can you prove that?

Comment: I think Carlo might be suggesting it's well known as an open problem. If so, then please know that MO generally closes well known open problems. We generally want questions for which there is *reasonable expectation* that someone may know an answer.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Is it really "well known"? Has anyone ever tried? Could you show me a link about that problem, because I just thought of it myself. How do you know its an open problem?

Comment: Stavros, I never affirmed it was well known. I thought Carlo *might* have been suggesting that. In which case, I was giving you a little information about site policy, in case you were not aware.

Comment: I believe one can strongly limit the possibilities with elementary means, and that with a little computation, one can either come up with a proof or a good lower bound for the next example.  Gerhard "Have To Go Get Lunch" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: I think that it is bad form to change your question *silently* to a dramatically different one (are there only 4? → are there infinitely many?) after a [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307535) is offered—especially since, as [@AlexM](https://mathoverflow.net/users/54780/alex-m) politely [observes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307531/is-it-true-that-there-are-infinite-palindromic-primes-that-when-squared-give-pal#comment765093_307535), you could easily have found the counterexample by searching the OEIS.

Comment: @LSpice Carlo Beenakker suggested that he not ask that as a separate question, but incorporate it into this question. It's true that the former question should not have been *erased* but rather added to, but I think maybe the OP feels besieged and confused at this point, what he is supposed to do.

Comment: Is it known whether there are infinitely many palindromic primes?

Comment: @domotorp, editing a dozen old questions in rapid succession just to add a tag isn't on. It pushes newer questions off the front page. Please limit yourself to three or four such edits a day.

Comment: @Gerry Sorry, I didn't know tag-edits also pushed them to the front. What is the policy when one creates a new tag? What is the correct way to tag old questions?

Comment: @domotorp, in my opinion, the correct way is to tag three or four old questions a day – but that's just my opinion, not site policy. It might be that this has already been discussed on meta (and, if not, you could raise the question there).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are in fact more than those 4, and they have [their own page on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A225603). Two conjectures, then, would be:

- are they infinitely many? I suspect so.
- are $2$ and $3$ the only ones formed with *decimal* digits other than $0$ and $1$? I suspect so.

Comment: I found that page by entering the sequence $2,3,11,101$ in the search field on OEIS and then browsing through the results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second conjecture could be proven inductively, from the outermost digits in. First, both the prime and its square must have an odd number of digits (excluding $11$), so the outermost digits must be $1, 2,3$. Then the 2nd digit can't affect anything higher, so it's restricted. This continues to the middle digit. Further, some careful juggling could say that other than the primes $2,3$, all of the primes must be made of $0,1$.